# GRUB loading.. at boot up and Windows 10 won’t load

Tags: linux, windows, boot

I create a bootable USB drive (16 GB) of Kali Linux with power iso

And create a different partition with disk manager in Windows 10 about 6 GB from the unallocated space

And restart the PC and installed Kali with graphical interface install

My settings is default

When I wanted to boot to Windows 10 later on, the PC boot automatically with Kali Linux

I tried to remove the USB drive and it display error : there is no device or something like that

I booted Kali with USB drive again and select graphical install and erased the partition that have the bootable option turned on I think it’s the partition that have the Kali image

And now when I boot up I see the message GRUB loading with or with out plugging the USB drive

I want to boot to Windows 10
and delete any files of Kali Linux that stuck in the C drive

Answer (score 0):

To fix Windows boot you need a Windows 10 installation USB/DVD.

Usually "Automatic Repair" started from recovery would fix booting if you have not deleted important (and hidden) partitions like EFI System and MS Reserved.

See "[Fix Windows boot](https://www.boyans.net/RepairWindows/repair-windows-boot.html)" for details if anything unclear.